# Adding content to a layout from a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

Suppose I have an application layout, and in their I yield for :head content as follows:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'scaffold' %>
    <%= yield(:head) %>
</head>
```

Suppose in that same application layout I call a partial to render the main menu.

```
<body>

    <p style="color: green"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>

    <!-- Main Menu -->
    <%= render :partial => 'menu/menu_main' %>
</body>
```

Is there any way, from within my _menu_main.erb partial to add content to the :head section of my application layout (say to add some css)?

Answer (score 19):

You have to use the **content_for** tag.

```
<% content_for :head do -%>
  *your code here*
<% end -%>
```

So, the code you put inside will apear on the **head** of your html file.

This railscasts episode explains it in more details: http://railscasts.com/episodes/8-layouts-and-content-for

Answer (score 8):

Here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10226010

In your `application.html.erb`:

```
<head>
  <% if content_for? :for_head %>
    <%= yield :for_head %>
  <% end %>
```

In your "specific" view:

```
<% content_for :for_head do %>
  Something-to-put-in-head
<% end %>
```

`:for_head` isn't predefined: naming it is up to you. It could be anything.

Comment: or just simply `<%= yield :for_head %>`, no need for the `if` statement