# Rails: How to include meta tags in views and not in application.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, meta-tags

I want to include meta tags in my homepage view. But I do not want to include it in the head section of the `application.html.erb` file directly, as this will cause it to include the meta tags on all pages which is redundant for my app.

Comment: Your home page view (defined by your routing) should have its own `erb` file that you can put them in.

Comment: I think a similar question was answered here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225645/rails-override-head-page-element-when-using-a-partial-or-a-specific-controll

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can put

```
<% if content_for?(:head) %>
  <%= yield(:head) %>
<% end %>
```

in `head` section of `application.html.erb` layout.

Then, in view in which you want to include these tags:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <!-- your tags -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: As a single line in the layout: <%= content_for?(:head) ? yield(:head) : "" %>

Comment: Or alternatively in a singe line: <%= yield :head if content_for? :head %>